# Parse query string into parameter names and values

Tags: javascript

I have a query string:

```
isUser=0&tokenId=911b7ce6-0ddb-4739-9a02-cd7304a2w&emId=19&url=dfsjgh&roll=s&commId=0
```

I would like to parse it and end up as follows:

```
var firstcharector=0;
var secondCharector=911b7ce6-0ddb-4739-9a02-cd7304a2w;
var thirdCharector=19;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "want to", not "wanna".

Comment: Use the search bar next time :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: "javascript" not "java scrpit"

Comment: Try reading the javadoc for String. I'm sure there's something there that will help.

Comment: Don't tag with Java nor JSP (nor C nor Python nor Flash etc) if you have a question about JavaScript. Further I also recommend to take some time apart to learn basic HTTP and web development concepts in order to get the terminology right. What you've there is called a query string. By the way, your `secondCharector` variable is in invalid syntax, but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA CODE**

giving java code because of 'java','jsp' tag in the question

```
String partialURL; // the url in post is partial
String urlArray[] = String.split("&");

String tempArray[] = new String[2];
    
// expected
/*
urlArray[0] = "isUser=0"
urlArray[1] = "tokenId=911b7ce6-0ddb-4739-9a02-cd7304a2w"
urlArray[2] = "emId=19"
*/

for(int i=0;i<urlArray.length;i++)
{
   tempArray = urlArray[i].split("=");
   urlArray[i] = tempArray[1]; // after '=' sign
}
```

javascript : no idea